# Is it possible to get InnoDB internal row ID?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6

I have a table without a primary key. I need to implement some kind of online schema change and I don't want to change insertion order. In MySQL documentation, I found [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html):

> If the table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB internally generates a hidden clustered index on a synthetic column containing row ID values. The rows are ordered by the ID that InnoDB assigns to the rows in such a table. The row ID is a 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted. Thus, the rows ordered by the row ID are physically in insertion order.

Is it possible to get this value from the table which seems to help to solve my problem?

Comment: Why doesn't it have a primary key?

Comment: It is served to me without a primary key and I would like to add it.

Comment: You can always just alter your table and include an auto incrementing id. Even if it generally holds no "value" for your code, you can then at least use it.

Comment: It's a fair question so I gave a +1, but really you should add a primary key as everyone else is saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to get this, because there also is no reason to. In a database rows are not sorted as long as you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` (or `UPDATE` or `DELETE`). You should **not** rely on "insertion order".

Just add a column serving as primary key...

Comment: The first thing I want to do is adding the primary key, but I didn't want to lock the table while adding the primary key. I was trying to find a workaround to prevent this. I am accepting the answer which replies my question.

Comment: Maybe the following is an option for you: `create table new_table like old_table; insert into new_table select * from old_table; alter table new_table add column id int auto_increment primary key; drop table old_table; rename new_table to old_table;` But please test this first, this is just out of my head...

Comment: I decided to use similar approach: 1. create temp_table like orig_table with primary key  2. Postpone insertion to orig_table for 2 minutes  3. Add after insert trigger to orig_table to insert to temp_table  4. Get logical backup of orig_table with transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ  5. Create new_table like temp_table  6. Restore from logical backup to new_table  7. Postpone insertion to orig_table for 5 minutes  8. Insert into new_table from temp_table  9. Atomic rename table orig_table to temp_table2 and new_table to orig_table.